# How to import CSS file content into a Javascript variable

Tags: css, webpack, es6-modules, shadow-dom, custom-element

Consider a very simply custom element using shadow DOM:

```js
customElements.define('shadow-element', class ShadowElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.styleTag = document.createElement('style');
    this.styleTag.textContent= `
.root::before { 
  content: "root here!"; 
  color: green; 
}
    `
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});
    this.root = null;
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.root = document.createElement('div');
    this.root.className = 'root';
    this.shadow.append(this.root, this.styleTag);
  }
})
```

```html
<shadow-element></shadow-element>
```

To get the CSS into the shadow DOM, I create a `style` tag, which I append into the shadow root. This is all working fine so far.

Now for more complex CSS I would like to author it in a file `shadow-element.css` which is in the same folder as `shadow-element.js`. Besides *seperation of concerns*  I also want IDE syntax highlighting and -completion for CSS authoring, so I really want the CSS in a separate, dedicated file.

I want to import the contents of that CSS file into a Javascript variable, like

```
import styles from './shadow-element.css'; // obviously doesn't work
```

On the project where this is being used we have a working **webpack** stack that allows importing CSS (and even SCSS), but unfortunately that imported CSS then becomes part of `bundle.css` -  which obviously is not at all useful, because the element uses shadow DOM.

Does anyone have a solution to this? I'm also open to alternative solutions, as long it won't require me to author my CSS in a .js file.

**Edit**: I am aware of the option of using `@import './shadow-elements.css';` inside the `style` tag, but I would much prefer a solution that bundles the imported CSS into my Javascript bundle (as part of the component code).

Comment: Full article on web-components styling [smashingmagazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/styling-web-components-using-a-shared-style-sheet/)

Comment: _“but unfortunately that imported CSS then becomes part of bundle.css - which obviously is not at all useful, because the element uses shadow DOM”_ - then don’t create a `style` element to append to your custom element, but a `link` instead, and set its `href` to the URL of the `bundle.css` …?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you are using **webpack**, you can use [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) to import a text file (CSS in your case) into a string:

```sh
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

And you can use it inline in each file:

```js
import css from 'raw-loader!./shadow-element.css';

customElements.define('shadow-element', class ShadowElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.styleTag = document.createElement('style');
    this.styleTag.innerText = css;
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});
    this.root = null;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.root = document.createElement('div');
    this.root.className = 'root';
    this.shadow.append(this.root, this.styleTag);
  }
})
```

Comment: how make the same for a svelte webcomponent=